# Using AsyncTask to send a single UDP packet

Tags: android

I am running a python server in my computer that is looping forever and waits for data to be received and when it  receives the data, it turns on\off the lights in my room.

In order to control it nicely I created an app that sends UDP packets to the server when I press a button to toggle the lights. My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        new Client(this).execute("init");
    }

    public void toggle(View view) {
        new Client(this).execute("toggle");
    }


    private static class Client extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket;
        String address = "192.168.1.243";
        int port = 6789;
        private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

        Client(MainActivity context) {
            activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                byte[] sendData = strings[0].getBytes();
                publishProgress("waiting for data");
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName(address), port);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                if (strings[0].equals("init")) {
                    // Receive result
                    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(6789);
                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[0];
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    publishProgress(new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength()));
                }
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (clientSocket != null)
                    clientSocket.close();
            }
            return address;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... strings) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(strings);
            activityReference.get().txtView.setText(strings[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this way, I create a AsyncTask every time I press the button, I wanted to know if it is a good practice or there is a better way to achieve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to create a new instance of the `AsyncTask`. You can not re-run it anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the help